# Contact Form CSS

Tags: css, forms, contacts

Help needed with centering the entire form.  also want the form to stay centered when browser window gets smaller and bigger and for input fields to adjust accordingly.

It seems to be half centered and half align left, but I played with that and it didn't want to move...

```css
/* CSS goes below this line! */

#ois-2 .ois-14-button, #ois-2 input[type='submit'].ois-14-button {
 background-color: #fd3f3f !important;
 border-color: #fd3f3f !important;
 border-width: 0px !important;
 font-size: 16px !important;
 font-family: 'Helvetica', Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
 height: 31px !important;
 border-radius: 7px !important;
 color: #ffffff !important;
 font-weight: 400 !important;
 width: 200px !important
}
#ois-2 .ois-14-email-input {
 padding-bottom: 4px !important;
 padding-left: 5px !important;
 padding-right: 2px !important;
 padding-top: 4px !important;
 text-align: left !important;
 width: 200px !important;
 border-radius: 5px !important;
 margin-top: 10px !important;
 margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
#ois-2 .ois-14-Name-input {
 padding-bottom: 4px !important;
}
#ois-2 .ois-14-name-input {
 padding-left: 5px !important;
 padding-right: 2px !important;
 padding-top: 4px !important;
 text-align: left !important;
 width: 200px !important;
 border-radius: 5px !important;
 margin-top: 10px !important;
 margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

#ois-2 .ois-14-title {
 text-align: center !important;
 font-size: 18px !important;
 font-family: 'Helvetica', Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
 line-height: 21px !important;
 font-weight: 700 !important;
 margin-top: 0px !important;
 margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
#ois-2 .ois-14-inner {
 border-color: #efefef !important;
 border-width: 1px !important;
 background-color: #e2e2e2 !important;
 border-radius: 4px !important;
 padding-bottom: 10px !important;
 padding-top: 10px !important;
 padding-left: 10px !important;
 padding-right: 10px !important;
}
#ois-2 .ois-14-outer {
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
}
#ois-2 .ois-14-form {
 text-align: center !important;
}

fieldset { float: left; width: 200px; border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
#left {margin-right: 20px; }
#right { margin-right: 0px; }
label {float: left;}
input {clear: both;; float: left}


/* End custom style */
/* End of file */
```

```html
<div class='ois-design'>

 <div id='ois-2' class='ois-design' >
<div class="ois-outer ois-14-outer">
 
<div class="ois-14-inner ois-inner">

<div class="ois-14-title">
Enter your name & email for access to our class schedule and amazing web special!</div>
  
<div class="ois-14-subtitle"></div>
  
  
<div class="ois-14-form">
   
<form method="post" id="ois-form-2" data-service="aweber" >
<div class="ois-14-name-input-wrapper">
<fieldset id="left">
<input type="text" name="name" class="ois-14-name-input ois-name-input ois-form-control" placeholder="Your Name"></fieldset>

<fieldset id="right">
<input type="text" name="email" class="ois-14-email-input ois-email-input ois-form-control" placeholder="Your Email"></fieldset>
</div>

<div class="ois-14-button-wrapper">

<input type="submit" class="ois-btn ois-14-button" />
</div>
</form>
  </div>
 
</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: If you're using `!important` you're probably doing something wrong. Also you can greatly simplify your CSS (and make it more readable) by using the shorthand rules.

Comment: A few other tips: don't use the `placeholder=""` attribute for input labels because the text disappears when it has a value. You also need to correctly encode the textual ampersand (to `&amp;`). And your markup is not correctly intended which hinders readability.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed a couple things, specifically removed all floats on the inputs, restructured your divs a bit more clearly and added a `margin: auto` to your form. I'd also suggest rethinking your markup and have less classes. A lot of them are redundant and do the same things.

```
fieldset { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px; 
    border: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}
```

```css
#ois-2 .ois-14-button, #ois-2 input[type='submit'].ois-14-button {
    background-color: #fd3f3f !important;
    border-color: #fd3f3f !important;
    border-width: 0px !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    height: 31px !important;
    border-radius: 7px !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    width: 200px !important
}
#ois-2 .ois-14-email-input {
    padding-bottom: 4px !important;
    padding-left: 5px !important;
    padding-right: 2px !important;
    padding-top: 4px !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    width: 200px !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    margin: auto;
}
#ois-2 .ois-14-Name-input {
    padding-bottom: 4px !important;
}
#ois-2 .ois-14-name-input {
    padding-left: 5px !important;
    padding-right: 2px !important;
    padding-top: 4px !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    width: 200px !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    margin: auto;
}

#ois-2 .ois-14-title {
    text-align: center !important;
    font-size: 18px !important;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    line-height: 21px !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
#ois-2 .ois-14-inner {
    border-color: #efefef !important;
    border-width: 1px !important;
    background-color: #e2e2e2 !important;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
    padding-left: 10px !important;
    padding-right: 10px !important;
}
#ois-2 .ois-14-outer {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
#ois-2 .ois-14-form {
    text-align: center !important;
    margin:auto;
}

body {
    /*width: 500px;*/
}

fieldset { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px; 
    border: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class='ois-design'>

        <div id='ois-2' class='ois-design' >
            <div class="ois-outer ois-14-outer">
                <div class="ois-14-inner ois-inner">
                    <div class="ois-14-title">
                        Enter your name &amp; email for access to our class schedule and amazing web special!
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="ois-14-subtitle"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        <div class="ois-14-form">       
            <form method="post" id="ois-form-2" data-service="aweber" >
                <div class="ois-14-name-input-wrapper">
                    <fieldset id="left">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="ois-14-name-input ois-name-input ois-form-control" placeholder="Your Name" />
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset id="right">
                        <input type="text" name="email" class="ois-14-email-input ois-email-input ois-form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <div class="ois-14-button-wrapper">
                    <input type="submit" class="ois-btn ois-14-button" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make the input fields float

With the width, you can use

```
input[type="text"] {
   width: 30vw;
}
```

Jsfiddle attached below

https://jsfiddle.net/fae4xb7e/